# Finding position and orientation

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a table and a image attached on top of it. I use a camera to capture the top side of the table with the image. I want to find the position and orientation of the table, with the help of the image orientation in the capture image. 
Can any one give me some hint? i am working in java

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: It'd help to include any relevant code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract orientation of an object using a binary image of your foreground object.

1. First, calculate the pixels of the object in question. This may be
   difficult in itself, depending on the conditions in your images.
2. Then calculate the [image moment values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) (very useful for image
   analysis) of the pixels in your object region.
3. Once you have those, you can build the covariance matrix,
   the eigenvectors of which define the orientation of the object.

You may also get basic orientation information via [Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).  Treat all the pixels of your object as observations in this method.